# Builder in Ruby is adding <xml/> to the markup>

Tags: ruby, xml

I am trying to generate this xml:

```
  <ns1:type>Account</ns1:type>
  <ns1:ids>2c92c0f83d60e055013d859f7f4873ee</ns1:ids>
  <ns1:ids>2c92c0f83d60e055013d859f7f2f73ec</ns1:ids>
```

I am using this code:

```
def generate_id_xml
  xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new

  xml.__send__(self.ons, :type, self.remote_name)

  objects.each do |o|
    xml.__send__(self.ons, :ids, o.id)
  end
  xml.xml
end
```

But it is producing:

```
<ins1:type>Account</ins1:type>
<ins1:ids>2c92c0f93d60e66d013d83e5845e04bc</ins1:ids
<ins1:ids>2c92c0f93d60e66d013d83e5847904be</ins1:ids>
<xml/>
```

Why is it adding the xml/ and is there a way to get rid of it?

I have this code and it is not adding the xml/ tag to its output.

```
def generate_xml
    xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
  objects.each do |o|
    generate_object xml, o
  end
  xml.xml           
end
#generate xml for an object
def generate_object(builder, object)
    builder.__send__(self.zns, :zObjects, 'xsi:type' => "ins1:#{self.remote_name}") do |a|
        object.to_hash.each do |k,v|
        a.__send__(self.ons, k.to_s.zuora_camelize.to_sym, v) unless v.nil?
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: I also just noticed that the first line of ids is missing the > endtag.

Answer (score 0):

`xml.xml` sends a method call  `xml` to builder - builder appears to work by handling all method calls as element names. Which interestingly causes it to do this in irb:

```
builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
 => <inspect/>
```

The `inspect` element appears because irb uses `Object#inspect` to show you the results of the call. Which builder then interprets as "add an empty element called 'inspect'"

I'm not quite sure how your other code works, but based on an earlier question, I do know that there is a wider context adding some containing elements, and it is possible that code there is somehow selecting or filtering the XML from the second working method. Have you tried isolating the working method and calling it directly?

When I try this variation of your code:

```
def generate_id_xml
  builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
  builder.namespace :type, 'contents'
  ['09876','65432'].each do |id|
    builder.ns2 :ids, id
  end
  builder
end
```

I get the following xml

```
<namespace:type>contents</namespace:type><ns2:ids>09876</ns2:ids><ns2:ids>65432</ns2:ids>
```

So it looks to me like the `.xml` on your last line is superfluous. Doesn't explain why your second code sample works OK . . .